# Spring boot error: Unable to load class 'com.mysema.codegen.model.Type'Unable to load class

Tags: spring-boot, junit, junit5

Spring boot error: Unable to load class 'com.mysema.codegen.model.Type'Unable to load class 'com.mysema.codegen.model.Type'
SpringBoot: 2.6.8,
querydslVersion = '4.3.1'

Answer (score 5):

Solution:

```
// update the query dsl version, e.g:
implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-core:5.0.0'
```